# .strip() on array using for loop in Python not working?

Tags: python

I'm trying to get rid of blankspace before and after an element in an array using .strip(), How do i get this to work correctly, I currently have :

```
ing1 = ['Nivea', 'Water,   GlyCerin, Caprylic/Capric Triglyceride, Squalane, Coco-Caprylate/ Caprate']

    ing1list = []
    for ele in ing1[1:]:
        ing1list.extend(ele.strip().lower().split(','))
    print(ing1list)
```

my output which is nearly right,  but still has a space before the second element is:

```
['water', '     glycerin', ' caprylic/capric triglyceride', ' squalane', ' coco-caprylate/ caprate']
```

Comment: Use `re.split(r'\s*,\s*', ele)`

Comment: That makes no sense. `ing1` is a list with a single string. Doing `ing1[1:]` will produce an empty list...

Comment: my mistake, I accidentally left out the apostrophe at the end of the first element,  there are actually 2 elements in the array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are stripping before splitting. You want to split before stripping.

```
ing1 = ['Nivea', 'Water,   GlyCerin, Caprylic/Capric Triglyceride, Squalane, Coco-Caprylate/ Caprate']

ing1list = []

for ele in ing1[1:]:
    sub_ele = ele.split(",")
    for ele2 in sub_ele:
        ing1list.append(ele2.strip().lower()) 

print(ing1list)
```

Output:

```
['nivea', 'water', 'glycerin', 'caprylic/capric triglyceride', 'squalane', 'coco-caprylate/ caprate']
```

Also, ing1 could probably be a string.

Comment: 'Ben Alan' your original answer, worked well:

        ing1list = []
        for ele in ing1[1:]:
            sub_ele = ele.split(",")
            for ele2 in sub_ele:
                ing1list.append(ele2.strip().lower())

        print(ing1list)

Comment: That solution didn't work with ing1 the way you had it, but somehow I knew what you meant. Reverted.

Answer (score 1):

You need to split your code into logically, first you will need to get the array proper values in from string,this will be iterated over to strip this can be achieved using list comprehension.

```
print([ looper.lower().strip() for looper in ing1[0].split(',')])
```

Output:

```
['Nivea', 'Water', 'GlyCerin', 'Caprylic/Capric Triglyceride', 'Squalane', 'Coco-Caprylate/ Caprate']
```

Or will need to use Lambda, filter, map to better organize.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution:

```
ing1 = ['Nivea, Water,   GlyCerin, Caprylic/Capric Triglyceride, Squalane, Coco-Caprylate/ Caprate']
ing1list = [x.strip() for x in ing1[0].split(",")[1:]]
print(ing1list)
```

You can first split the string, which returns a list, then you can provide `[1:]` for all elements except the first one, and use `.strip()` method, to remove the spaces.

Output:

```
['Water', 'GlyCerin', 'Caprylic/Capric Triglyceride', 'Squalane', 'Coco-Caprylate/ Caprate']
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to put your string in an array.
So I suggest you do something like this:

```
ing1 = 'Nivea, Water,   GlyCerin, Caprylic/Capric Triglyceride, Squalane, Coco-Caprylate/ Caprate'

ing1list = list(map(str.strip, ing1.lower().split(',')))
```